# Which of the two methods leads to the correct answer to this combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

The question goes; A team of 11 players is to be selected out of a set of 10 batsmen, 5 bowlers and 2 keepers. Find the total number of unique selections of players possible if at least 4 bowlers need to be in the team.

The first method is to make 2 different cases:
i) 4 bowlers are selected, and
ii) 5 bowlers are selected.

For the first case, 4 bowlers are selected (5C4) and 7 players are selected from the combined set of batsmen and keepers (12C7).

For the second case, 5 bowlers are selected (5C5) and 6 players are selected from the same combined set of batsmen and keepers (12C6).

The final answer this way comes out to be:
(5C4 * 12C7) + (5C5 * 12C6) = 4884

The second method is to select 4 bowlers out of the 5 (4C5) and then consider the remaining players (including the batsmen, keepers as well as the one remaining bowler) as a whole set and select the 7 remaining players out of that set (13C7).

The final answer is simply:
(5C4 * 13C7) = 8580

Just by my intuition, the second method is probably wrong because it tries to skip a step, but I could not pinpoint where the flaw is in the logic.

Which of this method is the correct way to approach such a problem and why exactly is the other method wrong?

I am probably sounding incredibly stupid here, but this seems to be a thematically similar situation to the Monty Hall Problem, at least in my head.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Is the only restriction the number of bowlers?  If so, the positions of the other players is irrelevant...is that right?

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on the cricket team? (How many wicketkeepers are needed? One?)

Comment: Assuming that the only restriction is on the bowlers, then the second method is wrong because it double counts the cases where you have $5$ bowlers.

Comment: @lulu Sorry for the vague wording of the question. No there aren't any other restrictions on the cricket team. The positions of the players are also irrelevant. We just need to select 11 players out of which at least 4 must be bowlers. Nothing more is necessary.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel There aren't any other restrictions.

Comment: @lulu How exactly does the second method double count the cases where you can have 5 bowlers? I am sorry I am a little slow at this.

Comment: Should have said, it multiply counts them.  The problem is that, if all $5$ bowlers are on the team, you have no way of knowing which one was the one that you picked out of the $13$, so you count those cases many times.

Comment: To be specific:  you count each of the $5$ bowler teams five times, once for each of the bowlers (according to which one of them you imagine was taken from the $13$).  Note that $9884-4884=4\times 924=4\times \binom {12}6$.  That factor of $4$ reflects the fact that you counted the $5$ bowler teams five times each, when you should have only counted them once.